# Stuck on C# parallel array and range matching homework

Tags: c#, arrays, range, matching

[Picture of hw problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0XX8.png)
I got this homework assignment where I have to write a program that shows the grade that the user receives based on the number they input. I think I did everything right but I get an error that says "use of unassigned local variable 'usersGrade'"  What did I do wrong? Please help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numOfWords; //user's input
    int[] numRanges = new int[] {0, 16, 31, 51, 76};
    char[] gradeLetter = new char[] { 'F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A' }; 
    bool found = false;
    double usersGrade;

    numOfWords = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); 

    int index = numRanges.Length - 1; 

    while (index >= 0 && !found)
    {
        if (numOfWords >= numRanges[index])
            found = true;
        else
            --index;
    }

    if (found)
        usersGrade = gradeLetter[index];

    label2.Text = $"You received an {usersGrade}";
}
```

Comment: You declare `double usersGrade`, but do not assign a value in the declaration. It is possible that a value will never be assigned. You need to make sure that a value is assigned before using the variable.

Comment: `double usersGrade` => `if (found)` is false then `userGrade` still unassigned when doing string interpolation. Try assign with default value `double usersGrade = 0`.

Comment: As an aside: I wouldn't choose a while loop for a search. A descending-order for loop combined with `break;` would read better.

Comment: `usersGrade` should also be a `char` to match the `gradeLetter` array's type.

Comment: Just for fun you can do it this way: `char usersGrade = gradeLetter.Zip(numRanges, (grade, num) => new { grade, num }).Reverse().First(x => x.num <= numOfWords).grade;`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I always enjoy and learn a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Look at these line of code:

```
 double usersGrade;
...
 if (found)
            usersGrade = gradeLetter[index];

        label2.Text = $"You received an {usersGrade}";
```

What if it's not `(found)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the error is due to the fact that if `found` is `false`, then `usersGrade` will be unassigned. To resolve this, you could just assign it to `0` to start with, which is the lowest legal value for the variable. But wait! Isn't `usersGrade` supposed to be a `char`? Why are we declaring it a `double`? You won't get a compile error because there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `double`, but if the user gets an `A`, we don't want to display `65` (which is the `double` representation of `A`). So let's just start them off with an `F`:

```
char usersGrade = 'F';
```

With this, you can also do away with the whole `if (found)` block, and simply do the assignment inside the `while` loop:

```
int index = numRanges.Length - 1;

while (index >= 0 && !found)
{
    if (numOfWords >= numRanges[index])
    {
        usersGrade = gradeLetter[index];
        found = true;
    }
    else
        --index;
}
```

But now that we look at that loop, it sure seems like there's some extra stuff going on: setting and decrementing the `index` value manually, and keeping track of a `found` variable. If we used a `for` loop instead, it would be much cleaner. The `for` loop already has the construct for us to assign a variable, loop while a condition is true, and decrement the variable. And we can just use the `break;` statement to break out of the loop when we assign the value. We can also move the declaration of `numOfWords` down to the assignment:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] numRanges = new int[] {0, 16, 31, 51, 76};
    char[] gradeLetter = new char[] {'F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'};
    char usersGrade ='F';
    int numOfWords = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    for (int index = numRanges.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        if (numOfWords >= numRanges[index])
        {
            usersGrade = gradeLetter[index];
            break;
        }
    }

    label2.Text = $"You received an {usersGrade}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `found` branch, userGrade is set, but on `!found` branch, it is not set.

```
if (found) 
{
    usersGrade = gradeLetter[index]; 
    label2.Text = $"You received an {usersGrade}";
}
else label2.Text = $"Error not found";
```

Alternatively you can avoid declaring userGrade overall and do this.

```
if (found)
    label2.Text = $"You received an {gradeLetter[index]}";
else label2.Text = $"Error not found";
```